# How to hide button in JavaScript when I click on an other one

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I want to hide the buttons when I click on one. So after reading StackOverflow questions and answers I founded this:

```
'click .stop' (event) {
        Session.set(this._id + "_spinningRng", true);

        document.getElementsByClassName('pause').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName('kill').disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName('cmdLogs').disabled = true;
```

But none of the 3 lines works.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to include jQuery as things get a lot easier :)

Then you would just do;

```
$('.stop').on('click', function() {
    $('.pause').hide(); // hides a element with the class pause (adds display:none;)
    $('.play').show(); // reveals a hidden element with class play
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Great yes I'll use this one ! Thanks